# Woocommerce search bar edit

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a search widget.

Here are screenshots of it when not clicked and when clicked:
Without click:

[image: without click]

When Clicked:

[image: when clicked]

What changes should I make to the Style.css?
I want to make the Search form appear without click and make the search bar width wider.

```css
4.1 PT Widget Search (start)*/
.widget_pt_search_widget .search-wrapper{
 position: relative;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
}
.widget_pt_search_widget .show-search {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 z-index: 1002;
 zoom: 1 !important;
 background:#fff;
}
.widget_pt_search_widget .show-search:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: inherit;
 z-index: -1;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 20px #00ADEF;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
 transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3;
 transition: box-shadow 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}
.widget_pt_search_widget .show-search:hover:before {
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #00ADEF;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
 transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
.widget_pt_search_widget .show-search .fa.fa-search {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 9px 0 0 1px;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}
.widget_pt_search_widget .show-search:hover .fa.fa-search {
 color: #00adef;
}
.widget_pt_search_widget #pt-searchform-container {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
}
.widget_pt_search_widget #pt-searchform-container.open .search-button {
 position: absolute;
 right: 42px;
 top: 2px;
 height:36px;
 width:auto;
 font-size: 14px !important;
 font-family: inherit;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
}
.widget_pt_search_widget #pt-searchform-container.close .search-button {
display: none;
}
.widget_pt_search_widget #pt-searchform-container .searchtext {
 height: 40px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
 background:#fff;
 color: inherit;
 z-index: 99;
 width: 100%;
 padding:0 15px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow:none;
 box-shadow:none;
}
.widget_pt_search_widget #pt-searchform-container.open .searchtext {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.30);
 -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.30);
 box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.30);
 padding-right:40px;
}
 /* Position in header (start)*/
.hgroup-sidebar .widget_pt_search_widget{
 margin-bottom:0;
}
.hgroup-sidebar .widget_pt_search_widget .show-search {
 display: inline-block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
 .hgroup-sidebar .widget_pt_search_widget {
  display:none!important;
 }
}
 /* Position in header (start)*/
/* 4.1 PT Widget Search (end)*/
```

Comment: What WP theme are you trying to customize?

Comment: Well i am using a theme named  StoreX [link](https://themeforest.net/item/storex-wordpress-woocommerce-electronics-theme/12946599)

Comment: Are using child theme?

Comment: yeah i am using child theme

Comment: Great. You will need to do all via header and jQuery. First - the width for the search window is set via div  `#pt-searchform-container` (probably hardcoded or via jQuery). Second - make it active on mouse hover and probably that will require some adjustments for mobile devices as there is no mouse hover.

Comment: there are like 4 or 5 #pt-searchform-container which one should or where should i make changes?

Comment: and i don't need it to hover i need the search bar to be permanently visible

Comment: There is only one `#pt-searchform-container` - all the rest what are you see in the code is a jQuery which you need to modify to have it longer and permanent visible.

Comment: okay.But i got no idea what things i need to change there are so many containers and i also have no idea what changes will do what.

Comment: Also if i make some changes and pase it in child theme style.css, no changes are seen.

Comment: If you don't see any changes from the child theme it may be that theme doesn't support child theme

Comment: Well that's the thing there are some changes that have been made by the theme department guys which work.And they have put all those changes into that child theme css, also i have tried some previously it takes time to do those changes.But in this case the changes are not being reflected

Comment: Also you have got a tip what to do to get that adjustments done. Nobody here will not do the work for you only will give you tips or solution if something is not working as you expect.

Comment: Like i tried to make some changes to the below code but no changes were observed

Comment: .widget_pt_search_widget .show-search {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 z-index: 1002;
 zoom: 1 !important;
 background:#fff;
}